# Swift: Create Live Photo From Video

Tags: ios, swift, video, photo

I am working on an application that will handle a lot of different types of media. This could be photos, videos, and audio. In the application I will display the media in a `UICollectionView` and the user can scroll through and pick which media they would like to view or play. It would be really nice if I could convert the last 5 seconds of video into a live photo and play the live photo as the `UICollectionViewCell` appears on the screen. Giving the impression that this media is a video and they can tap on it to play the video.

I know there has already been answers on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41224006/how-to-get-video-from-a-live-photo-in-ios) about getting the video of a live photo, but I am trying to **create a live photo from a video**. Preferably the last 5 seconds of the video.

**Question**

How do I create a live photo from a `.mov` file?

Comment: Any success for doing this ?